# while loop excluding a condition

Tags: c++, c

I'm increasing a pointer and decreasing a counter in a while loop. I want to exit the loop when the counter reaches zero or the pointer is equal to a max point (IF present). That if part is giving me the problem.

Consider the following:

```
char * pIt = utf8str;
char ** pEnd = 0;
size_t nVal = 10;
while ( 0 < nVal && (pEnd && pIt < *pEnd || true) )
{
    --nVal;
    ++pIt;
}
```

If `pEnd` is null, I want it to be excluded from the comparison so `pIt` will have no upper bound. Obviously the above code doesn't work since when `pIt >= pEnd` the 'or' comes into play and will always be true.

How would one do this?

Comment: Why are you checking pEnd at all then, in this code it difficult to puzzle out what you are trying to do and why you are trying to do it

Comment: You should keep in mind that when the first (the left one) in the `&&` evaluates to `false` the second one is **not** evaluated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok let's deconstruct your condition a bit. So at the top level we have two parts the counter and the iterator and both conditions must be met to continue so we have:

```
A && B
```

Now `A`, is the simplest and thats: `nVal > 0` (it's more natural at least for me to have what I'm comparing *to* on the right side).

Now be is a little bit trickier. Either `pEnd` is `null` and `pIt` has no upper bound, or `pEnd` exists. Which means `B == C || D`. So let's sub.

```
A && (C || D)
```

Now, if `pEnd` is null we want it to be true right? null is false, so we want true when false so what do we do ? `!pEnd`. That gives us C.

Finally we have D. Which is the case where `pIt` has an upper bound. `pIt < *pEnd`.

Let's put this all together and we have:

```
nVal > 0 && (!pEnd || (pIt < *pEnd))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nicely detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
while ( 0 < nVal && (!pEnd || pIt < *pEnd) )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are used to reading the ternary operator, this is pretty clear:

```
while (0 < nVal && (pEnd ? pIt < *pEnd : true))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
((pEnd == NULL) || (pIt < *pEnd))
```

Comment: This doesn't check the nVal value.

Comment: The point of answering his question is to give him something to understand, not something to blindly copy.

Comment: The `|| true` is so fundamental wrong so that I would consider to give a complete answer for at least that line.

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended as an answer but as a comment with code. *Shakes fist at SOs lousy comment-code options*

When you run into a brain-bending logic issue and sleeping on it is not an option, deconstruct with a for(;;) loop.

```
for (;;) {
    if (nVal <= 0)
        break;
    if (pEnd == nullptr) {
        // logic test you want here
    }

    --nVal;
    ++pIt;
}
```

Comment: @harper Every 5-10 years I break out the source for the MUD language I wrote in the mid-late 80s. This time, for extra humble pie, I went for the original 88-90s code. Amiga/SAS C: function protos don't get a return type 'less they retur a non-int. The code nearly filled my two floppies so comments are scare and I had to avoid wasteful carriage returns, whitespace and waffly (2+ char) variable names. When I can tell what it does, it's usually because I wish I couldn't: `rnd(){long x;time(&x);srand(x);return rand();`. Self reasonably deprecated; I argue for readable code any day :)